# bash: TAB command not found in .inputrc

Tags: macos, bash, inputrc, macos-sierra

I am trying to bash tab completion and added this inside .inputrc on mac os:

`set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete`

But when i source inputrc i get:
`bash: TAB command not found`

I had this working before on mac os with same setup.

Comment: Try `Tab: menu-complete` instead.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I tried other commands but none of them work. While set works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings look correct for what you are trying to accomplish. Just don't run `source ~/.inputrc`, instead use `bind -f ~/.inputrc` or just open new terminal window.